# HtmlUnit with Knockout JS

Tags: java, knockout.js, htmlunit

I am trying to automate a login page which appears to be using Knockout.js.

HtmlUnit doesnt seem to load the full page, it is missing all the input fields which makes it impossible to actually login.

I have tried ensuring that the JavaScript timeouts are set and have also enabled `NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController` I am waiting after the page has loaded using:

- `waitForBackgroundJavaScript`,
- `waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore`
- `Thread.sleep` (just for
  good measure)

I have even checked for additional windows (`WebClient.getWebWindows`), but there just seems to be the one.

It appears Knockout (assuming it is actually Knockout) is creating the inputs, is this just too much for htmlunit or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know problem (see https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/37).
Hopefully i will find some time to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the issue didn’t show up in my searches.  I will see if using an older version helps me.

Comment: Does this just affect Knockout or is it a more general problem that could impact the likes of angular, jquery, bootstrap, react etc?  I only ask because it doesnt seem to matter the source of the javascript, if the javascript changes the page I dont seem to be able to get those changed/refreshed elements.